# How to permit fess to clawl wordpress while rejecting google clawling

Tags: wordpress

I don't want my wordpress to be clawled by Google.
So, I checked 「Discourage Search Engine from indexing this site」 in WordPress.

However, I do want my Fess to clawle my WordPress.

How should I cofingure.

Comment: You can do that in your robot.txt

Comment: disallow googlebot and allow whatever fess uses

Comment: I solved the problem. I used form authentication.